# Past only select fields to out-gridview

Tags: powershell, out-gridview

How can I past only a selection of fields from an object to show in out-gridview, but still keep the whole object as a result.

For example, I retrieve an object that gives me:

```
$listcreds = get-listofcredentials

Id                    : 03c0e0c0-0951-4698-9ba9-a70508b5467f
IsLocalProtect        : True
Name                  : vsphere.local\Administrator
CurrentUser           : False
UserName              : vsphere.local\Administrator
UserNameAtNotation    : Administrator@vsphere.local
UserNameSlashNotation : vsphere.local\Administrator
UserNameOnly          : Administrator
DomainName            : vsphere.local
EncryptedPassword     : Veeam.Backup.Common.CCodedPassword
```

In the gridview I want to only see Name and ID. After the user selects the row desired, I would like to have the result as the same type of object again.

When I use select-object,

```
$selectedcred = $listofcredentials | select-object Name, Id | out-gridview -passthru
```

I get the result back but I would now have to search the original object again to get the other properties of that row.

What better way to do this?

Comment: Sometimes there no easy shortcut. Sometimes you have to go long way. ;-)

Comment: Normally, `Out-GridView` does not return any objects. When using the `PassThru` parameter, the objects representing the **selected rows** are returned to the pipeline.

Comment: I understand, but would like to only show certain columns of the object presented to out-gridview

Comment: `$cred = $listofcredentials | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $selectedcred.Id }`

Comment: Yes, that is how I do it now and where I have the luck that ID indeed is unique, but this isn't always the case. But I learned from the other replies, there is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the full object again in the list with `Where-Object`

This answer assumes the `Id` property is unique for every item in `$listcreds`

```
$listcreds = get-listofcredentials
$selectedcred = $listofcredentials | select-object Name, Id | out-gridview -passthru
$selectedcred = $listcreds | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq $selectedcred.Id}
```

I don't think there's a better solution here. If performance is a concern, you can convert the `Where-Object` into a `foreach` as below:

```
$listcreds = get-listofcredentials
$selectedcred = $listofcredentials | select-object Name, Id | out-gridview -passthru

foreach ($cred in $listcreds) {
    if ($cred.Id -eq $selectedcred.Id) {
        $selectedcred = $cred
        break
    }
}
```

However, the performance difference may be negligible or even negative.

Comment: OP did already state this in their post :)  "I get the result back but I would now have to search the original object again to get the other properties of that row."

Comment: @Daniel I didn't see that, whoops. However, I don't think there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies. Too bad there is no other way. The example using ID is indeed easy since the ID is unique, but I don't always have the option to make it completely unique without exposing some fields that I'd rather not show. But that is just the way it is :-)